# Pytest BDD : E fixture 'test_login' not found

Tags: android, appium, pytest, bdd, pytest-bdd

Hi need some help on how to fixed the error messages

```
E       fixture 'test_login' not found

>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, metadata, monkeypatch, pytestbdd_given_User logged into application, pytestbdd_given_trace, pytestbdd_then_trace, pytestbdd_when_trace, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory, trace
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

This is my **test_login.py**

```
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
from appium import webdriver
import pytest
import os



@scenario('../features/test.feature', 'Login scene')
def test_add():
    pass

class TestLogin:
    host = 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub'
    desired_capabilities={
        'platformName': 'Android',
        'deviceName': 'Galaxy J7 Pro',
        'platformVersion': '9',
        'appPackage': 'com.beaheromobile',
        'appActivity': 'com.beaheromobile.MainActivity',
        'udid': '52002b7fb8eb8489',
        'adbExecTimeout': 120000,
    }
    credentials={
        'email': 'shane08@silva.com',
        'password': '123456'
    }

    driver = webdriver.Remote(host, desired_capabilities)
    action = TouchAction(driver)

    @given('User logged into application')
    def test_login(self):
        self.driver
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(8000)
        loginbtn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[3]/android.widget.TextView')
        self.action.tap(loginbtn).perform()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(3000)
```

and this is my **test.feature**

```
Feature: Login
    A test login

Scenario: Login scene
    Given User logged into application
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in the way the test_login.py file is being defined. pytest_bdd will look for the scenario associated with the test_add() and will automatically run the conditions associated with the scenario such as given, when, then etc. This means that definition for @given condition should not be having any pytest identifiable method name such as test_*. Else this is make pytest_bdd believe that this is another test case and will look for the corresponding fixture for the same. This approach is working for me.

So please rename the test_login() method to something else like login1(), as below. This will ensure that the test is working fine.

```
from pytest_bdd import scenario, given, when, then
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction
from appium import webdriver
import pytest
import os



@scenario('../features/test.feature', 'Login scene')
def test_add():
    pass

class TestLogin:
    host = 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub'
    desired_capabilities={
        'platformName': 'Android',
        'deviceName': 'Galaxy J7 Pro',
        'platformVersion': '9',
        'appPackage': 'com.beaheromobile',
        'appActivity': 'com.beaheromobile.MainActivity',
        'udid': '52002b7fb8eb8489',
        'adbExecTimeout': 120000,
    }
    credentials={
        'email': 'shane08@silva.com',
        'password': '123456'
    }

    driver = webdriver.Remote(host, desired_capabilities)
    action = TouchAction(driver)

@given('User logged into application')
def login1(self):
    self.driver
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(8000)
    loginbtn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[3]/android.widget.TextView')
    self.action.tap(loginbtn).perform()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

did you create your feature file,, in this case you have to structure your project.

First, your test class have to be separate of your code that you want to test

https://github.com/AndyLPK247/tau-pytest-bdd/tree/chapter-4/tests

look this repo this is how you have to structure your project

feature file  cucumber.feature

```
 Feature: Cucumber Basket
  As a gardener,
  I want to carry cucumbers in a basket,
  So that I don't drop them all.


  Scenario: Add cucumbers to a basket
    Given the basket has "2" cucumbers
    When "4" cucumbers are added to the basket
    Then the basket contains "6" cucumbers
```

then you test_steps_def.py

```
from pytest_bdd import scenario, parsers, given, when, then
from cucumbers import CucumberBasket


@scenario('../features/cucumber.feature', 'Add cucumbers to a basket')
def test_add():
    pass


@scenario('../features/cucumber.feature', 'Remove cucumbers to a basket')
def test_remove():
    pass

@given(parsers.cfparse('the basket has "{initial:Number}" cucumbers', extra_types=dict(Number=int)))
def basket(initial):
    return CucumberBasket(initial_count=initial)


@when(parsers.cfparse('"{some:Number}" cucumbers are added to the basket', extra_types=dict(Number=int)))
def add_cucumbers(basket, some):
    basket.add(some)


@when(parsers.cfparse('"{some:Number}" cucumbers are removed from the basket', extra_types=dict(Number=int)))
def remove_cucumbers(basket, some):
    basket.remove(some)


@then(parsers.cfparse('the basket contains "{total:Number}" cucumbers', extra_types=dict(Number=int)))
def basket_has_total(basket, total):
    assert basket.count == total
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), we should specify a keyword argument `target_fixture` in `@given` decorator.

So your new definition should look like below:

```
@given('User logged into application', target_fixture="test_login")
def test_login(author):
    pass
```